# Xcode JSON arabic text black instead of red

Tags: ios, json, parsing, arabic

I have a project including a JSON file which contains Arabic text.
I copied the text from a Word Document file into the JSON file in Xcode. 
As far as I know, the correct bits of text in the JSON file are usually shown in red and
the incorrect bits are shown in black color.
This is what it looks like in Xcode:

[image: JSON file with Arabic text]

There are plenty of parts in my JSON file where text is shown in black, hence it must be incorrect. When I run the app, which should output the arabic text in a tableview, the
tableview is shown as empty.
Thus, there must be a problem with the JSON file.

I also checked it on http://jsonlint.com/ with the JSONLint Validator. It showed me the following error message in the red box at the bottom:

[image: JSONLint Validator error message]

Here is the JSON file containing the Arabic text:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gxdqmh2l9lr7cv/MyFavoriteDishes_ARA.json

I don't know how to fix it! It's frustrating. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Something is not properly escaped.  This would generally be the fault of the code generating the JSON string from whatever source objects were used.  (Note that you have little chance of generating valid JSON if you simply paste extended-character-set data into a JSON "template".)

Comment: (Explain more precisely where the JSON came from.)

Comment: The JSON template was already in XCode. I copied the Arabic text from an Document which was written in Microsoft Word. And the file extension of the Word file is .docx.

Comment: If you copied the text into a "template" and did not process it through NSJSONSerialization then that's your problem.

Comment: (To do it properly you should create an NSMutableDictionary with the data and then process through NSJSONSerialization.)

Comment: The color is: red are strings, black are syntactic characters. So the JSON file shown in the screen shot is almost correct. There however seems to be a problem with the doubles quotes in the title. Though they seem to be properly escaped at first sight, there must be a problem there. Both jsonlint and the coloring indicate it. Please add the JSON file as text to your question (and not as a screenshot). Then we can further investigate it.

Comment: I just added a Dropbox Link to the JSON file at the bottom of my post.